# Accessing a non-global JS variable within a scope/function dynamiclly

Tags: javascript, dynamic

So I'm just starting with BabylonJS and I have a variable that I'm declairing within the `createScene` function named `scene`. I have this function that takes objects from an array and converts uses them to populate my `scene` (the target) with meshes:

```js
let objectsFromArray = []

for(let i in sceneObjects){
    let currentObject = sceneObjects[i];
    let objectFunc = get(BABYLON, currentObject.path)

    objectsFromArray.push(
        objectFunc(...currentObject.params)
    )

    for(let action of Object.keys(currentObject.actions)){
        objectsFromArray[i][action] = objectsFromArray.actions[action]
    }
}
```

The array outside of the `createScene` function that has all of the generic objects/meshes stored in it like this:

```js
let sceneObjects = [
    {
        path: "MeshBuilder.CreateBox", 
        params: [
            "box", 
            {
                width: 30,
                height: 1
            }, 
            this["scene"] //<---- This is the issue
        ],
        actions: {
            position: new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -5, 3)
        }
    },

]
```

Notice the `this["scene"]` array at the end of the params array. This is here because I need to dynamically pass the `scene` variable locally declared within my `createScene` function as a target for BabylonJS to know where to place the mesh. Obviously `this["scene"]` is targeting a undefined global variable instead of the local one. How do I dynamically target a variable that was declared locally/in scope?

P.S. Sorry for misuse of terminology/stupidity, mostly programing as a hobby

Comment: You can't access variables from anywhere but a higher scope. You need to do whatever you're doing in the same scope or get the scene in the scope you want by returning it from a function or passing it in.

Comment: Thanks o/. I seemed to have fixed it by shoving all my variables (`scene` included) inside a class's constructor and then putting the `createScene` inside it as a method.